# Is it possible to send an email to a list of users using Marketo API and PHP

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7, marketo

I've got a Drupal website and I'd like to send an email via Marketo whenever a new post is created. I've got the Drupal side of things covered (I know how to create the custom module that will be triggered whenever a new content us created).

What I don't know is whether:

1) Marketo API allows for this?
2) How? As when I was trying to follow [this](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/asset-api/create-email/) tutorial, I got stuck on the `$clientId` and `$clientSecret` as these values are now available under `Integration/LauchPoint` nor in `Integration/Web Services`

Thanks!

Comment: Your q is more likely to receive replies if you could illustrate how exactly you got stuck and what code you wrote...

Comment: I didn't write any code yet. I don't know whether Marketo supports what I want to do and if it does, where can I get the `clientId` and `clientSecret` key. Like I said, I'm fine writing the code in Drupal, the weak link in this case is Marketo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an admin account or something. http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/custom-service/

Here is how you can obtain your client id and secret